# Determine the type of each singularity.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

I got the following question, and I think I got the correct answer with justification but I am note sure. Can anyone verify if this is correct?

> For each of the following functions, find all of it's singularities and determine the type of each singularity. If the singularity is a pole, also find the order of this pole:
>
> 1. $\cos(1/z)$
> 2. $\sin(z)/(1-\cos(z))$
> 3. $z/\sin(z)$

Here's my attempt at the problem:

> 1. The following is the Laurent Expansion of $\cos(1/z)$:
>              $$\cos(1/z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{z^{-2n}}{(2n)!}$$
>              We find that there is a singularity at $z = 0$. Since there are infinitely many terms of negative powers, we find that the singularity at $z = 0$ is an essential singularity.
> 2. Consider the following function:
>              $$\frac{\sin(z)}{1-\cos(z)}$$
>              There are singularities whenever $z = 2\pi n$, $n \in \mathbb Z$. Consider the following limit:
>              $$\lim_{z \rightarrow 2\pi n}\Big|\frac{\sin(z)}{1-\cos(z)}\Big| = \infty$$
>              Therefore, all of these singularities are poles. Consider the following limit:
>              $$\lim_{z \rightarrow 2\pi n} \Big|\frac{z\sin(z)}{1-\cos(z)}\Big| = 2$$
>              Therefore, each of these poles is a pole of order $1$.
> 3. There is a removable singularity at $z = 0$ and essential singularities at $z = \pi n$, $n \in \mathbb Z \backslash \{0\}$. For $z = 0$, we can make $f(z) = 1$ to remove the singularity. For $z = n\pi$, there exists no $n$ such that $\lim_{z \rightarrow n\pi}z^nf(z) = C$. Therefore, $z = \pi n$ are essential singularities.

Comment: In (3) you should be looking at$$\lim_{z\to n\pi}(z-n\pi)^kf(z)\ .$$This will show you that the singularities (other than $z=0$) are poles of order $1$.  There is a similar error in the working for (2), though your answer has turned out correct.

Comment: Yeah, I think all of these are fine with David's contribution.

Comment: For $z / \sin(z)$ what you wrote is not correct. Since $h(z) =\sin(z)$ is meromorphic (it is entire) $\frac{1}{h(z)}$ and $\frac{z}{h(z)}$ are meromorphic, so their singularities are poles.

Comment: @David I see! So I should multiply by $(z-z_0)$ instead of $z$. Thanks for the help!